# How can I get my music from iOS GarageBand to iOS iTunes so iPhone apps can use them?

Tags: ios, garageband

I want to use my developed music in iOS Garageband for apps in iPhone. How can I do this?

Comment: The only way to add music to iPhone in a way that normal (read: non-Apple) applications can access it is by syncing with a computer. (Well...that's not entirely true. If an app supports using a third-party service to download the file directly into the app, that would work too. But your question is accessing files already on the device, and for that, my first sentence is correct.)